# Extracting data from excel via threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, excel

I am trying to extract data from excel with multiple threads using the OleDBAdapter to do this along with the Fill() method. Each thread receives a new OleDBAdapter along with the startIndex and rowsCount to extract.

My problem is when each thread starts they all get stuck on the Fill() method. I've tried different connection strings and adapters to see if would help but no luck so far. It seems like the first connection the excel worksheet locks it until its over and therefore I lose the effiency of threading.

The only approach I havent tried so far is copying the file with different names i.e. add threadIndex to the end and then I could have multiple connections since the data source is different but this seems like the worst thing I can do.

Comment: I suspect the adapter is opening the sheet exclusively, meaning anything else is just stuck until the first one is done.

Comment: Excel is NOT a database and thus parallel/multi-threaded access to the same Excel file won't work and if it you get it to work somehow it will behave very strangely... that is not a robust way to deal with an Excel file... please describe the problem you try to solve... perhaps there are other options...

Comment: The excel files are stocks that are sent to me and I need to extract the relevant data from the file. This data can vary is its presentation and therefore cannot be parsed effiecently and therefore I need the whole sheet. Reading through Excel with the Excel objects has been much slower than treating it as a DataTable. The files can differ in size from 10kb to 100mb which makes the simple Fill() of the whole file very slow (sometimes up to 10 mins).

Comment: @BrainPicker There are several libraries (some free, some commercial) that access Excel files directly which amazingly fast... are your files XLS or XLSX ?

Comment: @Yahia I am using the same method to open csv,xls,xlsx and dbf files.

Comment: @BrainPicker dbf files ? are those old dbase files ?

Comment: @BrainPicker for DBF I don't have a clue... for XLS, XLSX and CSV I can recommend some library (commercial)... is that an option for you ?

Comment: @Yahia Not really, no. My boss is very stingy on these issues. I was hoping there would be another approach to this.

Comment: @BrainPicker sorry, I don't know another approach :-(